# Simple estimate involving Poisson Kernel

Tags: calculus

Let $Q_\epsilon (x)=\frac 1 \pi \frac x{x^2+\epsilon^2}$.

Let $\Delta_\epsilon (x)=\frac 1{\pi x}-Q_\epsilon(x)$ when $\mid x\mid\geq \epsilon$ and $\Delta_\epsilon (x)=-Q_\epsilon(x)$ when $\mid x\mid<\epsilon$.

I want to estimate $\mid \Delta_\epsilon(x)\mid \leq A\frac \epsilon {x^2}$.

I was able to show this in the case $\mid x\mid<\epsilon$ but I don't know how to do in the other case.

Difficulty: I wanted to estimate each term in $\Delta_\epsilon$ but it doesn't seem right because clearly $\frac1 x$ is not estimated by $\frac\epsilon {x^2}$ when $\mid x\mid\geq \epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing common denominator in the right way we have
$$
|\Delta_\epsilon(x)|= \dfrac{\epsilon^2}{\pi |x|(x^2+\epsilon^2)},
$$
now from this we use the inequality
$$
2|x|\epsilon \leq x^2+\epsilon^2,
$$
which follows from expanding $(|x|-\epsilon)^2\geq 0$, and then obtain
$$
|\Delta_\epsilon(x)|\leq \dfrac{\epsilon^2}{2\pi|x|^2\epsilon} = \dfrac{\epsilon}{2\pi x^2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm wondering if you could resolve the confusion. 1. How can we see from the first inequality to conclude $0\leq\Delta_\epsilon (x)\leq\frac1 {2\pi x}$? All I can see is $-\frac 1\pi+\frac 1{\pi x}\leq \Delta_\epsilon (x)\leq -\frac 1{2\pi}+\frac 1{\pi x}$. 2. For the first equality, I get $\mid \Delta_\epsilon (x)\mid=\frac{\epsilon^2}{\pi\mid x\mid(x^2+\epsilon^2)}$.

Comment: @jk001: You're absolutely right. There was an algebra mistake that I just kept carrying over; shame on me! Thanks for catching it, I've edited the correct way to get the *right* bound.

Comment: @jk001: I will say, notice that this bound (as I proved it) has no restriction on $|x|\geq \epsilon$; it holds for all $|x|\neq 0$. On the other hand, the function $Q_\epsilon(x)$ obeys better bounds for $|x|<\epsilon$, namely $|Q_\epsilon(x)|\lesssim  1/|x|$.